# No sound - please help

Tags: sound, pavucontrol

please help. I have no sound and no loudspeaker icon on the top tight bar in Ubuntu.

When I start 'pavucontrol' there is just a label "Establishing connection to Pulseaudio".

What can I do?

Comment: What OS/release are you running?

Comment: i installed the latest ubuntu 3 weeks ago. unfortunately, i don't know how to find out the actual release.